# Error in query in vb.net returns incorrect double value

Tags: mysql, .net

I have a problem on my query in vb.net. I need to Update the status of reservation table to "completed". Here's my query
Update reservation SET status = 'completed' Where resID = '" & tbresID.text & "'. The value of textbox tbresID is two reservation ID which is 1017 and 1018. Everytime I run the program it shows me the error message "truncated incorrect double value: '1017,1018'". But when I run thecquery on mysql workbench it returns no error. How can I fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple values, do you need 'in' instead of '='?

"Update reservation SET status = 'completed' Where resID in '(" & tbresID.text & ")'"

Comment: thank's for the help. I already fix the problem sir. I remove the single quotation in where clause.